# What's a safe network file system protocol that I can expose to the public internet?

Tags: networking, nas

I have a home DIY NAS (Debian) that I occasionally use from remote devices. The NAS has an SMB file server and currently I access it remotely by using SSH (private key encryption) and SSH port tunneling

```
ssh nasuser@example.com -L 448:localhost:445
```

Then connecting to `smb://localhost:448` on the remote client.

This doesn't work all that well when I am using my Android TV remotely as I have to use Termux and do the whole ssh setup before having access.

My understanding is that it's not safe to expose my SMB server's port directly to the public internet, is there a network file sharing protocol with client support on all major platforms that is safe enough to expose over the internet?

Answer (score 3):

Never expose any network file system. Instead, use a VPN (or ssh tunnelling), and then expose the network file system over the VPN.

Also keep in mind that a network file system over longer distance will be quite slow, and not a pleasant experience.

If setting up the VPN or ssh tunnelling is too much effort, automate it.

Comment: Also look into sshfs - althiugh Ive obly used it Linux to Linux.  (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chaos9k.sshfsandroid&gl=US looks like it coukd work Android to Linux)

Comment: Microsoft exposes Azure shares through SMBv3, so I guess this can be considered as safe: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows

Comment: @PierU these are mounted on internal VMs, and access is controlled through the Azure infrastructure. You can also mount them via NFS or via fuse on Linux VMs, but that doesn't make those methods safe...

Comment: No method is safe if you do not administrate properly the server

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that it's not safe to expose my SMB server's port directly to the public internet, is there a network file sharing protocol with client support on all major platforms that is safe enough to expose over the internet?

SSH has one built-in: SFTP. Many Android file manager apps support it, and it can be handled like a mountable filesystem through `sshfs`.

WebDAV may be an option, though support for it is relatively rare (sometimes it might be labeled "Nextcloud" as that's the most common WebDAV use).

(SMB is considered to be mostly unsafe, but a *big* part of that was due to bugs within the Windows in-kernel SMB server specifically. Alternative SMB server implementations (e.g. Samba) are much less risky – both because of a different code base that is not affected by the same kind of bugs, and because a userspace smbd process on Linux is significantly easier to confine than a kernel driver on Windows.

So if you run a Samba-based SMB fileserver, it's halfway ok. Still would recommend *at least* an IP-based firewall allow list on top, though, but at least Windows-oriented exploits aren't going to work with it.

Unfortunately, many Android apps do not support new SMBv3 features such as transport encryption; they'll do the absolute bare minimum to support SMBv2 if you're lucky, and will require SMBv1 otherwise; in both cases you're left with essentially a clear-text protocol. Also, using SMBv1 over WAN is not a good experience even if it were secure.)

An easy solution to all of the above is to stop exposing the network file system protocol and instead expose a VPN protocol, as VPN servers are designed with remote access in mind (just like SSH is) and are much less risky to expose in general. Then, once you've connected to the VPN, use SMB or NFS or whatever you want.

Comment: Dumb question, can you connect to multiple VPNs simultaneously? For example, could I be connected to both my work VPN and my home VPN?

Comment: Technically yes, especially if neither of them provides a default route (i.e. both are "split tunnel" mode). If one of the VPNs does, or especially if both do, it can get a little unpredictable.

Comment: I have seen NAS devices offer the ability to connect to a file system remotely without any VPN. They use a DDNS and some kind of file server protocol (WebDAV I think?). Would these NAS devices be considered a considerable attack vector or is this safe enough for a DIY replacement of Google Drive?

Comment: The VPN isn't there just to _have_ the ability to connect to a file system (it is already possible to use even SMB or NFS without a VPN), it's to _limit_ that ability, as even with purely HTTP-based protocols (like WebDAV or a web-browser interface) you might have a NAS [like this](https://www.theregister.com/2018/01/08/wd_mycloud_nas_backdoor/) or [like this](https://www.theregister.com/2014/08/05/synologys_synolocker_crisis_its_as_bad_as_you_think/).

Comment: What about exposing an SFTP server to the public internet?

Comment: SFTP runs over SSHv2, which is considered secure as a protocol, though it still depends on implementation. OpenSSH is usually considered safe to expose to public, other SSH/SFTP servers may be less hardened but most of them are okay.